# Arrow Animation

Tags: animation

I have a question regarding an animation in a blender file that I was able to find online. This is the file: http://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=208349&d=1356231992

Essentially it is a moving arrow where the base does't move but the arrow tip moves to a specified location.

I just want to know exactly how it's done. I've tried to replicate it but it's not working out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

How this works:

There are two objects that make up the arrow:

The core of the arrow is just a plane:

[image]

On a different layer there is another object that works as the tip of the arrow (I changed the color for clarity)

[image]

The basic animation is an array modifier. By keyframing the count from 1 to 50 over the course of 50 frames.

[image]

Adding the arrow tip as the End cap to the array will make the arrow complete:

[image]

[image]

The path the arrow follows is determined by a bezier curve object.

[image]

By adding a curve modifier to the arrow object, the array will be deformed along the designated curve.

[image]

**EDIT**

There is indeed an error on the original file you uploaded. The tip of the arrow is rotated 180 degrees in object mode. The trick for getting the correct direction is this: The array is generating clones of the original object (the arrow's core) in the X axis. The tip of the arrow should point in that direction.

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate! That's exactly what I'm after the only problem is the orientation of the arrow head. Whenever I add the arrow head the orientation is off i.e. the arrow head is facing the wrong direction. Do you know how to correct this?

Comment: Not sure why my last comment disappeared. Anyway. Thanks mate that's what I'm after, my only problem is the arrow head after I make it the End Cap. When I do this the orientation of the Arrow Head is off i.e. turn 90 degrees so the side of the arrow head is attached rather than its base to the array. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks for your help so far! Much appreciated

Comment: @AndrewAC Go the arrow and in edit mode rotate it in the opposite direction to where it if currently facing. That should fix the orientation.

Comment: @AndrewAC see edited answer.

Comment: Thank all, I've managed to get the arrow facing the correct direction. However, it's now turned 90 degrees from the x-axis rather than facing the  x-axis. Additionally the size of the arrow head has decreased so that the core of the arrow is larger. Thanks for your help so far and if you have any tips for these problems that would be much appreciated

Comment: If you made the tranformation in Object Mode you have to "apply" your transformations using Ctrl+A (Rotation & Scale)

Comment: Cegaton you're a legend! Cheers mate and to everyone that contributed!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're Animating the **Count** when you should be Animating the **Position**, what exactly is happening is that you just keep creating back part of the arrow next to another one just like that:

[image]

but you should animate the position:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My understanding is the  the OP's asking for an explanation on how it's achieved, (the array and curve modifiers)  as opposed to there being a problem with the linked file.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have understood the basic principles of animating an arrow traveling a curve. My problem is that my arrow becomes twisted as it travels along the curve. What is it that I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Mostly you are using the Answer field to write a question. Why not pose that as a new question?